# After remaining inactive for a long time, what gear would need to be replaced and what gear can be cleaned/reused?

Tags: equipment

It's been over 5 years since I brewed my last batch.  I'll be moving in a few months into a new place and I'll be able to start brewing again, the problem is what equipment is toast from sitting idle after that long and what equipment can be cleaned/sanitized and put back to use?

I am going to assume that metal/glass stuff is on the clean/sanitize list, but what about plastic fermenters?  Hoses?  Airlocks and other plastic/rubber stuff?  What about chemicals like PBW, Yeast nutrient/energizer, or sanitizers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should all be good.  As long as the plastic items haven't dried out and cracked, they just need to be cleaned and sanitized.  I quick trial run with just water will tell you if certain items are leaky or unusable.